# сё or сие as a pronoun

Tags: выбор-слова, история-языка, местоимения

In modern Russian you could say:

- Это дерево – дуб.
- Это – дерево.

In older times you might have used сей in its neuter form for the first sentence:

- Сие дерево – дуб.

But what was used for the second sentence? Would it be сие or would it be сё?

- ? *Сие – дерево.*
- ? *Сё – дерево.*

On the one hand, there are expressions like:

- то да сё (то и сё, то-сё)
- ни то ни сё (declined like: ни с того ни с сего, ни тем ни сем)

But I get the impression that сё is only used as a rhyming pair with то in the above idioms, and that for other normal uses the pronoun would be сие. Is this correct?

For instance in ruscorpora.ru there are phrases like:

- Понятия не имею, что сие означает
- Сие было правдой
- одновременно с сим
- вместе с сим
- И с сим встала и вышла

(the declensions differ only in the nominative and instrumental: сё/сем versus сие/сим)

Or is it possible that сие and сё were both valid and were a contrasting pair with the same usages as это and то? Was сё ever used on its own, rather than just in a couple of fixed expressions involving то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Сие* is an adjectival pronoun in the full singular nominative first person neuter, *се* (not ***сё*) is a nominative pronoun (originally, the short form of the same). Both are dated and in the modern language they have been replaced with *это*.

*Сие дерево — дуб* means "this tree is an oak", *се — дуб* means "this is an oak". In the first case, the word "this" modifies "tree" like an adjective would; in the second case it's a subject in its own right.

Nominative deictic and demonstrative pronouns are invariant, they don't change by gender or number: *се дуб, это кошка, то ножницы, вон мама*.

English doesn't convey the difference between adjectival and nominative deictic pronouns on the syntactic level, but many other languages do.

Note that you can also use the full form *сие* in the nominative sense, as your examples show, but, technically, not the other way around.

> But I get the impression that сё is only used as a rhyming pair with то in the above idioms, and that for other normal uses the pronoun would be сие. Is this correct?

In this rendition, with *ё*, it is. Normally, *то да се* would be expected, but it doesn't rhyme.

> Or is it possible that сие and сё were both valid and were a contrasting pair with the same usages as это and то? Was сё ever used on its own, rather than just in a couple of fixed expressions involving то?

In Proto-Slavic, there was a trichotomy of *this (next to me) / that (next to you) / that over there (far away for both of us)*. The Russian reflexes of the Proto-Slavic words for these concepts are *се / то / оно*.

*Оно* has been relegated to the role of a personal pronoun (replacing the reflexes of **jь* which still form the stems of oblique cases of personal pronouns in the third person singular), and is not actively used in the demonstrative sense anymore except in set phrases *время о́но* etc.

*Это/этот* is a relatively new (c. XVI century) replacement for *се/сей*. For quite a long time they coexisted in neutral speech.

Comment: In ruscorpora.ru when searching for `се, SPRO & nom`, the only phrases I get are: 1) mostly paired то/се, 2) a few misspellings or variants of всё равно, and 3) only one sentence with се not paired with то, from 1790: "И се явился паки взорам нашим седящ на коне борзом в древней Отцов своих одежде, Муж, основание града сего положивший и первый которой на Невских и Финских водах воздвиг Российский Флаг доселе не существовавший." Is it known for sure that they pronounced it се and not сё, and how was that determined?

Comment: @ghostarbeiter: they who? The main corpus starts around 1700, by that time it long since had been only used as a Slavonicism.